# Adding @Around advice to @RestController methods

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-restcontroller

Is it possible to add @Around advice to @RestController ?

I tried anything but with no success.

Below is my simple logging aspect

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Around("execution(public * zbc.sxw.rest.*.*(..))")
    public void logRestCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println("Write code for before advise");
        joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("Write code for after advise");
    }
}
```

The classes under the rest package are all annotated with @RestController annotation.

If I change the .rest.  to .ctrl. which include @Controller annotated classes the Aspect is working fine.

Any idea what is the problem with @RestController ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your restcontroller have an interface? I've done something like what you are doing now, only with jersey REST-services, and it stopped working whenever there was an interface involved..

Comment: What do you mean have an interface? The RestControllers classes not  implement any interface but there are members which declared as interfaces (after all, this is Spring)

Comment: Hi, can you please turn on debug logging and post the output of the application when starting (maybe, you have to use pastebin or similar)?

Comment: This is pretty old but removing public from the expression might work.

Answer (score 1):

try add @Componet annotation on your aspect class
e.g.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Around("execution(public * zbc.sxw.rest.*.*(..))")
    public void logRestCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println("Write code for before advise");
        joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("Write code for after advise");
    }
}
```